# Easiest way to fetch Facebook friends info in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, api

What is the easiest way to fetch Facebook friends info (names,birthdays and etc) in JSON format. I'd like not to use FB iOS SDK if possible use UIWebView.

I think it is possible with 2-3 http requests. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the below function to get your faceBook Info (logged in user info)

```
- (void)fetchUserDetails {
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid=me()", @"query",nil];

[fb requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                                 andParams:params
                             andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                               andDelegate:self];}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you add code for signing in? I have problems with it...

Comment: Download the facebook iOS SDK from [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) and facebook login implementation from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/)

Comment: I don't want to use SDK at all.

Comment: then my friend you cant.. as there is already support.. then why do you want to re-invent. The Graph API does that for you